# How did the Saviors know the group would try to reach the Hilltop?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-walking-dead

In the season 6 finale of *The Walking Dead*,

> the group has to reach the Hilltop so that Maggie can get checked by the OBGYN over there.  However, when making the trip, they keep getting blocked by the Saviors, who were obviously waiting for them.

**How did they know that the group would make that trip?**

Comment: Related: (Science Fiction & Fantasy SE) [How did the Saviours know where Rick and the team would be travelling in the Season 6 finale?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/124037/7957)